# laravel reactjs pusher: presence channel response is 302

Tags: reactjs, laravel, pusher, pusher-js

I'm trying to make a reactjs application where an user can only login to one device at the time with the same user credentials. Unfortunately it isn't working.

I'm trying to authenticate a presence channel with reactjs to laravel but I get a 302 response.

reactjs:

```
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher("9028d58568392772df59", {
        cluster: "eu",
        forceTLS: true,
        authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
        auth: {
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token
            }
          }
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe("presence-HandleCredentials");
    channel.bind("sameCredentials", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User', function ($user, $id = 1) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

broadcast:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:web']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

When I added this ['middleware' => ['auth:web']] I got the error. Before I added that I got a 403 error.

in the config\app.php I uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,`

Are there any tutorials out there that are build with laravel and reactjs for a presence channel?
does anyone know how to get past this 302 redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same issue with my laravel-websockets and laravel echo.
In my case I was unable to solve the 302, as Broadcast was unable to authenticate my logged in user. I was trying to subscribe to my private channel. So the workaround i found was that i manually created a POST route in web.php as "/broadcasting/auth". This is what my front-end requests to. So The updated code in web.php is as follows.

```
Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function(Request $request){
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    array(
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'useTLS' => false,
        'host' => env('APP_URL'),
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http',
    )
);
return $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('channel_name'),$request->request->get('socket_id'));
```

});

I was creating my own websocket that is why i had to mention the host & port within the options, you don't need to use it if you are Using Pusher. You can also add other middlewares to the routes if needed.
You have to comment out the following line in **app/providers/BroadcastServiceProvider**:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Broadcast::routes();
    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

so that the request can reach my **broadcasting/auth** route in web.php.

Try this. now this should return a 200 when the broadcasting/auth is requested by your client end with response of an auth code. Do let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Okay, so It returns a 200 code with an auth key, but how can I join the channels? `Echo.join('game.0')
            .here((users) => {
                alert("In the channel!");
            })`

This is not triggering :(

Comment: Well you need to configure that on your own. I recommend this [link](https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo/episodes/8)  for you to understand presence channels on Laravel. However u also need to look at your browsers chrome dev-tools network tab. In network tab select **WS** and you can see your websockets there. Make sure that the subscription to the channel succeded and there is no message with **Invalid Signature** in the Messages of the web socket. Do let me know for any other issues.

Comment: It just does not work, no subscription messages at all :/ I opened a new post [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177471/laravel-broadcasting-how-to-auth-to-a-presence-channel)