# Laravel Broadcasting, how to auth to a presence channel?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I'm trying to join a presence channel (Public channels work well), but I can't get this to work:

**Vue** code:

```
mounted(){
        Echo.join('game.' + "0").here((users) => {
                alert("In the channel!");
            })
            .joining((user) => {
                console.log("Someone entered");
            })
            .leaving((user) => {
                console.log(user.name);
            })
            .listen('GameEvent', (e) => {
                console.log("Hey")
            });

            Echo.channel('NewSentence')
                .listen('NewSentence',(sentence)=>{
                    alert("HOLA");
                });
    }
```

I'm trying to join the channel "game.0". As I'm using Laravel Passport I need to authenticate myself with a token, and that is working. Sending the auth request for Laravel Echo returns a key, but the JavaScript events are not triggering `.here()`, `.listening()` ....

**BroadcastService provider boot function:**

```
public function boot() {
        Broadcast::routes(["middleware" => "auth:api"]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('game.0', function ($user,$id) {
   return ['id' => $user->id];


});
```

**The auth route:**

```
Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function(Request $request){
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    array(
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'useTLS' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http',
    )
);

return $pusher->socket_auth($request->request->get('channel_name'),$request->request->get('socket_id'));
});
```

Do I need to do something extra to make it work? This is the auth request:

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
**GameEvent** event:

```
class GameEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $gameEvent;
    public $gameId;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($gameEvent, $gameId) {
        //
        $this->gameEvent = $gameEvent;
        $this->gameId = $gameId;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn() {
        //return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        return new PresenceChannel('game.0');
    }

    public function broadcastWith() {
        return $this->gameEvent;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I've hardcoded the names: 'game.0' is now hardcoded in the `routes/channels.php` route, in the Echo connection and in the GameEvent. I also removed `broadcastAs()`. After entering the laravel-websockets debugging dashboard I found that the channel I want to subscribe doesn't even appear. It looks like it won't start a connection, but I can't figure out what it going on.

I hardcoded the

Comment: Can u also upload the Event file which you are broadcasting?

Comment: @Kuldeep post updated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that the Echo is not listening on proper channel. First of all the Echo.join is using channel game.0 in which 0 is a user's id, and i don't think that there is actually a user with id 0. Secondly, you are broadcasting as

> GameEvent

and Echo is connecting to channel named **game.{id}** I suggest that you either remove the **broadcastAs()** function from your event file or listen on **GameEvent**. Also use the websocket dashboard for testing this. The dashboard will be available at

> /laravel-websockets

route automatically, which is available only for local environment so make sure that environment is local in your .env.

Use the debugging dashboard provided by laravel-websockets to send data to channels, first connect to your web socket within the dashboard then just enter the channel name, event name and data in JSON format and hit send on the dashboard.
[image: Laravel Websockets Dashboard Image]
Try finding out if that helps with resolving your problem.

I also recommend thoroughly reading [laravel's official documentation on broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting) as well as [laravel-websockets debugging dashboard guide](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/debugging/dashboard.html).
Also update what you got in result to this question.

Comment: After this answer, I've hardcoded the names: 'game.0' is now hardcoded in the `routes/channels.php` route, in the Echo connection and in the GameEvent. I also removed `broadcastAs()` as you said. After entering the laravel-websockets dashboard I found that the channel I want to subscribe doesn't even appear. It looks like it won't start a connection, but I can't figure out what it going on

Comment: Can u update the question with updated files... i think u can solve the issue using the dashboard... also the issue is sometimes with the namespace... check the dashboard log when you broadcast an event...

Comment: I updated the post with these changes. The dashboard doesn't give any clue, the messages through the channel are sent correctly, and no errors are showing in the console. It just does not connect to the presence channel

Comment: What do you mean by the dashboard doesn't give any clue? Can you see that your echo subscribed to game.0 channel in the dashboard? If you can then just try sending an event from the dashboard, check if it works... I was able to solve my issue using the same dashboard.

Comment: No, that's the thing, I can't see my echo subscribed to the game.0 channel. No subscriptions to that channel.

Comment: Firstly open the dashboard and make sure u are connected in the dashboard, then reload the page where u listen for channel in a new tab, then check if the dashboard has subscribed message... the dashboard logs every subscription  event.

Comment: I told you that it does not appear any subscription message for game.0 channel, the rest of channels yes, but the game.0 presence channel no

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `broadcastAs()`, you need to put a `.` before channel name in `Echo.join()` according to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#broadcast-name)

```
Echo.join('.game.' + "0")
```